# Just upgraded to Mountain Lion and I have to buy iPhoto again?

Tags: upgrade, photos.app, mac-appstore, macos

I originally was on Leopard.  Then I got the free upgrade to Snow Leopard.

I bought Lion when it was released and removed it after a few months because it made my machine too slow.  I upgraded the RAM and upgraded to Mountain Lion yesterday.

But iPhoto is missing?  During the last two years I bought (from Apple) an iLife disc.  Remember discs?  lol

Anyway, it's iLife 11 so technically I could install it from disc but I like the app store experience.  Do I really have to pay $15 again for iPhoto in order to get it from the app store?  Or is there another way?

Comment: After installing mountain lion.
I'm not able to open iPhoto..
I dont know what is wrong with me..
I have to again purchase ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you've never purchased it from the App Store, you cannot re-download iPhoto from the App Store (unless you buy it again).

The only way you get re-download rights to iLife on the App Store is if you either purchased it from the App Store or bought a Mac that does not come with a software re-install disc.

Comment: That really sucks.  Pixelmator did the same thing.  Have to repurchase versions.  Oh well.  Thanks.

Comment: No need to repurchase it if you have the disc. You just don't get updates via the app store

Comment: I have an MBA. I was thinking of downgrading to Lion, installing iPhoto (free) and then upgrading again to Mavericks. Though it takes long, I was thinking that would work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

You can always re-run the disc based installer and avoid re-purchaing the app from the App Store. Eventually you will buy a new Mac which will then allow you to claim the App Store licenses for iLife without paying additional fees.

I'm stuck in the same boat with Aperture. The convenience of the App Store isn't enough to make me want to re-pay for the software I have a DVD based install.

Answer (score 5):

The same thing happened to me! I didn't have a disc and didn't want to pay for it on the App Store so I made a Genius Barn appointment. I explained my situation and they pulled out an external hard drive with all the software on it and re-installed it for free. If your close to an Apple store and have enough time, I would try that.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot download it from the App store. Once installed from the disc, you get free updates though.